# Distinguish between different causes of VOIP application start

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

VOIP application are restarted automatically in iOS in several cases:

- Initial install
- Reboot of device
- Crash of VOIP application

I am looking for way to distinguish between them.

I checked launchOptions from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, but both for Reboot and Initial install are nil (I didn't check for a crash).

I am looking for a way to distinguish programmatically these three cases. I am fine with private API's.

Comment: @meaning-matters: Do you want to put it as an answer (it's quite interesting info and I would be happy to upvote it)?

Comment: The user can also kill the app explicitly, which won't look much different to rebooting the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial install can be detected by saving something in NSUserDefaults; if it's not there yet ...

Reboot vs. Crash is being discussed elsewhere, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022357/distinguish-between-an-iphone-app-crashing-and-being-killed).

And perhaps looking at iOS [uptime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488481/getting-ios-system-uptime-that-doesnt-pause-when-asleep) might help.  Could be combined with NSUserDefaults.