# Background fetch is not working after killing the app

Tags: ios, swift, background-process, background-fetch

I'm trying to get data from url with background fetch. My func tries to get data and if there is a new data, it sends local notification. Background fetch works after about 10 - 20 minutes when i minimize the app. But when i kill the app (double click home button and close app) it doesn't work. I waited about 1 hour but it didn't work. I am using background service in android and it is working successfully. Is there any way to get data from url and send local notification when app is closed? I am using Xcode 6 and swift 1.2

Comment: Hope this help you http://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-ios-swift-tutorial

Comment: I think the only way to achieve this is to use [PushKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/PushKit_Framework/index.html), there is a question about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068762/will-ios-launch-my-app-into-the-background-if-it-was-force-quit-by-the-user).

Comment: Use Push Notification to re-start terminated app.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Background Fetching will NOT happen in your app after the user has killed it in the multitasking UI. This is by design.

Take a look at [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW7) that mentions:

> Apps that support background execution may be relaunched by the system
>   to handle incoming events. If an app is terminated for any reason
>   other than the user force quitting it, the system launches the app...

and

> In most cases, the system does not relaunch apps after they are force
>   quit by the user. One exception is location apps, which in iOS 8 and
>   later are relaunched after being force quit by the user. In other
>   cases, though, the user must launch the app explicitly or reboot the
>   device before the app can be launched automatically into the
>   background by the system.

As you noticed in the documentation, there's only 1 exception when the app will be relaunched if it was force killed: by using location services. Unfortunately this does not apply to you.

Also, you cannot detect if the app was force killed by the user. Check this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022357/distinguish-between-an-iphone-app-crashing-and-being-killed).

Comment: is there any possibilities to execute code after app termination in ios 10 swift 3.0 ???

Comment: @PatelJigar No. iOS 10 behaves the same as iOS 9 and 8 in this manner. Again, this is by design.

Answer (score 4):

The Background Fetching will NOT Update in your app after the user has killed app from background. it is not Possible